# asp.net razor real time validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have a bit of a problem and I would like to ask if it is possible and if yes how. For example you have a Create form for Reservation in Car Rental.

```
Car model containts information like:
brand,model,costPerHour, NumberOfSeats(how many seat 4,5,7,...)
```

In Create form - dropdown list:

```
<div class="editor-label">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarId, "Car")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.DropDownList("CarId", String.Empty)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarId)
</div>
```

Under dropdown there will be slider with number of persons that are gonna travel.

```
<div class="editor-label">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonsInCar)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonsInCar)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonsInCar)
</div>
```

Is there a way to limit editor for PersonsInCar, depending on Car.NumberOfSeats (from 1 to number of seats of selected car)? 
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Not without using ajax to call a controller method based on the selected car, which returns a value indicating the number of seats.

Comment: Could you please give some example of such a ajax or some source ?

Comment: There are millions of examples of using ajax on the web. You need to do some research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",        //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: ajaxUrl,       // Location of the service
    data: "",       //Data sent to server in your case CarID Selected
    contentType: "",        // content type sent to server
    dataType: "json",   //Expected data format from server
    processdata: true,  //True or False
    success: function (json) {//On Successful service call
    var result = json.name;
    $("#dvAjax").html(result);
    },
    error: ServiceFailed    // When Service call fails
});
```

And you must write a method in controller that returns Number of Seats in json, this method receives CarID parameter